# Redirecting a request to another class

Tags: php, oop

I have three classes. `Class A`, `Class B`, `Class C`. What I am trying to do, send a request to Class B form Class A, and Class B must redirect that request to Class c.

May be a simple example from below will give a certain idea.

```
class classa {
    public function __construct() {
        $obj_classb = new classb;
        $obj_classb -> someRequest(); // This request must go to Class B and query the Class C        
    }
}

class classb {
    //This class must do something, which is going to redirect any sorts of request it receives to the next classc
}

class classc {
    public function someRequest() {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Explain what issue you're trying to solve with this hack.

Comment: Well, One of the reason is, I am trying to group some class with a similar `namespace`. As per my example `class B` is the just the namespace class and `class C` is actual intended class. Another reason is, some what like observer class, to monitor the requests and update a different set of classes.

Comment: It is not a task, it is a solution. Weird solution.

Comment: @zerkms, yeah its weird, but ain't weird, also fun? BTW, I have updated my comment, please read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a "redirector" class by overriding the [`__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) method like this:

```
class classb {
    private $obj_classc;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->obj_classc = new classc;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->obj_classc, $name), $arguments);
    }
}
```

Of course this will "forward" only method calls; if you are interested in forwarding property getters/setters etc you will have to override more [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

Choosing the forwarding target can also be arranged (in this example it's just an automatically-created `classc` object; but you can pass it as a parameter in the constructor or provide it in any other way you choose).

**Update:** Magic functions you need to override to forward property accesses:

```
public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->obj_classc->$name = $value;
}

public function __get($name) {
    return $this->obj_classc->$name;
}

public function __isset($name) {
    return isset($this->obj_classc->$name);
}

public function __unset($name) {
    unset($this->obj_classc->$name);
}
```